# apply a user MaxAllowedCall on a wcf Method

Tags: c#, wcf, behavior

I'd like to enforce call restrictions on my services methods.
Those restrictions should return a FaultException when the maximum amount of calls per client is reached.

The first solution I found was to code the logic within the service:

```
 public class MyService: IService
 {

    public IList<Entity> FindAll()
    {
        if(VerifyQuota(Context, "FindAll", this.GetType().Name))
        {
           //retrieves entities
            return entities;
        }
        else
        {
           //throws a FaultException
        }
        return null;
    }

    private bool VerifyQuota(ContextEntity context,string Method,String Service)
    {
      // counts the occurences of calls made by the user
      // returns true if user can access method , false otherwise
    }
 }
```

It works but :

- It's rather ugly
- It pollutes my method's logic
- code redundancy is too high and maintainability is realy bad.

I am looking for a more elegant solution and thought of using a IOperationBehavior but I don't know where I can find te user Identity.

OperationContext.Current is not set and neither is Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

So here are my questions:
  - are behaviors the best way to implement this kind of functionality ?
  - If so where can I find the user's identity (or logon)
  - If not where can I put this code so it fits into WCF architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing with Behaviors and found out I could access the operationalContext.Curent in a IparameterInspector.

IparameterInspector implementation:

```
class QuotaInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    #region IParameterInspector Members

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        if(ServiceSecurityContext.Current != null)
        {
            if(ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity != null
                && ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.AuthenticationType == "MembershipProviderValidator")
            {
                String Account = String.Empty;
                String serviceComponent = String.Empty;
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name))
                    Account = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
                if(OperationContext.Current != null &&
                    OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher != null
                    && OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime != null
                    && OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Type != null &&
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Type.Name))
                    serviceComponent = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Account) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceComponent) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(operationName))
                {
                    //Apply Quota verification here
                                            //throw FaultException if quota is reached
                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

IOperationBehavior implementation:

```
class QuotaOperationBehavior : Attribute,IOperationBehavior
{
    #region IOperationBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new QuotaInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }

    #endregion

}
```

To apply the quota to a method you just have to declare an attribute:

```
public class MyService: IService
 {

    [QuotaOperationBehavior]
    public IList<Entity> FindAll()
    {
       //retrieves entities
        return entities;
    }
 }
```